# How do network engineers keep a video stream going while switching networks?

Tags: video-streaming

This is not an in-depth technical question (unless it becomes that).

While watching a sports stream online (ESPN), if I switch Wi-Fi networks, sometimes it will keep on streaming without missing a beat (I know "sometimes" is a loaded word).

How is this accomplished?

Thanks

Comment: Liking with the help of smart network hardware equipment, redundant network, etc. Is this a question about television broadcasting?

Comment: Your browser will notice that it lost the connection and then simply reconnect to the server. So it has nothing to do with the network engineers. Rather it's the software engineers that wrote the browser.

Comment: @SpiderPig I would say video buffer is the biggest factor of why it tends to work seamlessly. The "sometimes" the asker indicates could mean there isn't enough buffer loaded when the switch network switching and reconnecting to the server happens which would cause the interim interruption.

Comment: Yes, but most of the time only part of the video will be in the buffer, so the browser still has to reconnect to load the rest.

Comment: Short answer: Buffering on the client side.

Comment: If you watch a video on Youtube.  Right click and choose "Stats for nerds".  You can see the health of the buffer and how long is buffered.  E.g 50 secs.  You can disable the network cable and it will still keep playing until the buffer is drained.  So I would say when it fails, either the internet connection wasn't good enough to establish a big enough buffer for the amount of data required or you were not watching the video long enough to build up the buffer.  Either way it's typically up to the client side player to manage its buffer and maintain the experience during networking issues.

Comment: Thanks everyone for emphasizing **buffer**.  And special thanks to @HelpingHand for pointing out _stats for nerds_.  That is an excellent way to see in real-time what is actually happening.  (Apparently I'm too new to vote up any answers).